# AndEngine abstract subclass - App not starting

Tags: java, android, andengine, abstract

I'm using Andengine and Android Studio. I'm trying to create an Activity called MyBaseGameActivity which is abstract and extends from BaseGameActivity. My actual game extends from this abstract class. Inside the abstract  class I'm loading a startScene and a gameOverScene, which all games I create should use. The reason for that is that startScene and  gameOverScene should always look the same for every game. However when I try to run the app just nothing happens. The app gets installed, but when I click on the app icon it says "app not installed". When I try to start another testgame which directly extends BaseGameActivity everything just works fine.

Did I miss to care about something when implementing MyBaseGameActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found out myself - stupid mistake, I had two identical activity entries in my AndroidMainfest.